# Django template breaking DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, datatables

I am trying to implement a basic DataTables table in my Django app.  It only appears to fully render when my template variables are not included in the template:

`current_orders.html`

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- DataTables.net -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/jquery.dataTables.min.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.dataTables.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#current_orders_table').DataTable();
    });
    </script>

    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.4/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.4/material.yellow-deep_purple.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

  </head>
  <body>
      <table id="current_orders_table" class="display mdl-data-table <mdl-js-data-table></mdl-js-data-table> mdl-shadow--2dp">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Customer Name</th>
            <th>Date order was placed via Email</th>
            <th>Opportunity ID</th>
            <th>BTMW Reference</th>
            <th>Sales Order Number</th>
            <th>Supplier PO Numbers</th>
            <th>SAS Date of Delivery</th>
            <th>Serial Numbers Recorded?</th>
            <th>INCare Reference Number</th>
            <th>Contract Start Date</th>
            <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">INCare Notes</th>
            <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Ongoing Progress</th>
            <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Actual Status of Order</th>
            <th>Status Updated</th>
            <th>Invoice Raised</th>
            <th>Invoice Notes</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          {% for order in orders %}
          <tr>
            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{ order.customer }}</td>
            <td>{{ order.order_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ order.op_ref }}</td>
            <td>{{ order.btmw_ref }}</td>
            <td>{{ order.sales_order_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ order.supplier_po_numbers }}</td>
            <td>{{ order.sas_date_of_delivery }}</td>
            <td>{{ order.sas_notes }}</td>
            <td>{{ order.serial_numbers_recorded }}</td>
            <td>{{ order.incare_ref_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ order.contract_start }}</td>
            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{ order.incare_notes }}</td>
            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{ order.ongoing_progress }}</td>
            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{ order.actual_status }}</td>
            <td>{{ order.status_updated }}</td>
            <td>{{ order.invoice_raised }}</td>
            <td>{{ order.invoice_notes }}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>

      </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

`views.py`

```
def current_orders(request):
    orders = get_list_or_404(Order, closed=False)
    return render(request, 'tracker/current_orders.html',
                  {'orders': orders})
```

This will happily render a table, but without all the extra goodness; search bar, pagination, sort arrows etc..  Yet when I remove the `<tr> to </tr>` lines from the `<tbody>` , those with `{{ }}` template variables, these elements render fine.
From chrome DevTools I can see there is an error, but my JavaScript knowledge is minimal and it has me stumped.  Looking online this doesn't appear to be a common problem so my assumption is that I am missing something basic.  Any help would be much appreciated.

`Chrome DevTools error`

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of
>   undefined(anonymous function) @
>   jquery.dataTables.min.js:92m.extend.each @ jquery.js:384m.fn.m.each @
>   jquery.js:136(anonymous function) @
>   jquery.dataTables.min.js:92m.extend.each @ jquery.js:384m.fn.m.each @
>   jquery.js:136m @ jquery.dataTables.min.js:85h.fn.DataTable @
>   jquery.dataTables.min.js:163(anonymous function) @
>   (index):18m.Callbacks.j @ jquery.js:3148m.Callbacks.k.fireWith @
>   jquery.js:3260m.extend.ready @ jquery.js:3472J @ jquery.js:3503

and line 92 of dataTables.min.js:

```
    g.slice());q=[];g=this.getElementsByTagName("thead");0!==g.length&&(fa(o.aoHeader,g[0]),q=qa(o));if(null===e.aoColumns)
    {p=[];g=0;
    for(i=q.length;g<i;g++)
       p.push(null)
    }else 
     p=e.aoColumns;g=0;
    for(i=p.length;g<i;g++)
    Ga(o,q?q[g]:null);
    hb(o,e.aoColumnDefs,p,function(a,b){
    la(o,a,b)});
    if(s.length){
    var u=function(a,b){
    return a.getAttribute("data-"+b)!==null?b:null

};
h(s[0]).children("th, td").each(function(a,b){
var c=o.aoColumns[a];
   if(c.mData===a){
var d=u(b,"sort")||u(b,"order"),e=u(b,"filter")||u(b,"search");
```

Comment: This might be unrelated, but I see 17 columns in the body and only 16 in the header.  DataTables can get broken very easily when the table is not well-formed.  That's just at first glance, maybe I'm not seeing something...

Comment: Oh bloody hell.  Yes, that was it, thankyou!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your header only contains 16 columns but your body contains 17.  Make the number of columns match, otherwise DataTables will get confused and throw an error.

Comment: How did you see that?  Is this something you just check for, or are you unusually attentive?  Maybe I overthink/overcomplicate these things? I'm genuinely interested as I just wasted a bunch of time over this simple error.

Comment: Only reason I looked for that is because I've had similar issues with DataTables in the past.  It works great, as long as all your elements are there, otherwise it doesn't work at all. And the error you posted made me think there was something missing, so I checked.  Not to get too philosophical, but I think we've all been there -- 10% of the work takes 90% of the time.  Then later you start to see patterns in your mistakes and their fixes.  I'm convinced more and more that this whole business is just a bunch of patterns...